# How to stop Finder trying to reconnect an unavailable network share?

Tags: macos, networking, macbook-pro, shared-folders

My Mac laptop was connected to my home network, to copy files from my XP desktop. Now the laptop is on the road, but every time I open Finder, I get a message box telling me that it can't get to that network share anymore. The network share isn't listed in anywhere that I can see.

How do I tell it that the network is gone? How do I avoid this happening next time?

The message is this:

```
Connection failed
The server [...] may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently I had accidentally created an alias to the share, and was inadvertently cursoring over it.